# Do i18next have keyPrefix option?

Tags: typescript, i18next, react-i18next

I'm using `i18next` and `react-18next` for my project. When using `useTranslation` from `react-i18next` we have a nice option of "keyPrefix" to help us reducing code duplication. But sometimes I need to use i18next outside a component, so I wonder if it has any abstractions like `useTranslation` that can let me use `ns` or `keyPrefix` without repeating it everytime I use the `t` function?

I tried looking around i18next's documentations, but I can't find anything (yet?).

I tried to do it myself with adapter pattern, but the typescript support would break since I can't get the type of the key of `t` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is even easier to do so in `i18next`. I would just use `react-i18next`'s [documentation](https://react.i18next.com/latest/usetranslation-hook#optional-keyprefix-option) as an example:

```js
// having JSON in namespace "translation" like this:
/*{
    "very": {
      "deeply": {
        "nested": {
          "key": "here"
        }
      }
    }
}*/
const { t } = useTranslation('translation', { keyPrefix: 'very.deeply.nested' });
const text = t('key'); // "here"
```

And in `i18next` (as mentioned in it's [documentation](https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/essentials#accessing-keys-in-different-namespaces)):

```js
// for different namespaces than default one
i18next.t('translation:very.deeply.nested.key');
// it is recommended to use the ns option:
i18next.t('very.deeply.nested.key', { ns: 'translation'});
```

And if you need to set it as default in some specific JavaScript files, check: [`i18next.getFixedT(lng, ns, keyPrefix)`](https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#getfixedt).

Hope this answer helps